# Give an example of $W \neq(U_1 \cap W) \oplus (U_2 \cap W)$ if $V=U_1 \oplus U_2$ and $U_1,U_2,W$ are the subspaces of $V$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, vector-spaces, direct-sum

> Give an example of $W \neq (U_1 \cap W) \oplus (U_2 \cap W)$ if $V=U_1 \oplus U_2$ and $U_1,U_2,W$ are the subspaces of $V$

Let $U_1=\{(x,0)\}$ be a subspace of $\mathbb{R^2}$ over $\mathbb R$.

Let $U_2=\{(0,y)\}$ be a subspace of $\mathbb{R^2}$ over $\mathbb R$.

Let $W=\{(x,y)\}$ be a subspace of $\mathbb{R^2}$ over $\mathbb R$.

Then:
$$
(U_1 \cap W) \oplus (U_2 \cap W)=((x,0) \cap(x,y))\oplus((0,y)\cap(x,y))=\\
(\emptyset)\oplus(\emptyset)=\emptyset \neq W
$$

This seems a too easy  example and I feel like I'm missing something. Am I in the correct direction?

Comment: In your example, $W=\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: $((x,0)\cap (x,y)) \neq 0$

Comment: Could I pick $U_1=(1,0), U_2=(0,1), W=(1,1)$?

Comment: @JJR can a single vector be a subspace in itself?

Comment: @Yos no since every linear combination of the vector has to be in the vector space

Comment: A single vector forms a subspace if and only if it is the zero vector. Also, the example in the question is not an example, since it uses unspecified values $x$ and $y$. If you want those to vary, you should say things like $\{\,(x,0)\mid x\in\Bbb R\,\}$ instead; here it is clear that $x$ varies.

Comment: @JJR is this a correct example: $U_1=\begin{bmatrix}x&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$, $U_2=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&y\end{bmatrix}$, $W=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\z&0\end{bmatrix}$ where $U_1,U_2,W$ are subspace of $M_2(\mathbb R)$?

Comment: @Yos that fails to satisfy $U_1\oplus U_2=V$.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen why can there exist $V=\begin{bmatrix}x&0\\0&y\end{bmatrix}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classic example of this is having $U_1,U_2,W$ be three distinct lines through the origin in a space of dimension$~2$ (both intersections are reduced to the zero vector, but $W$ is not).

Comment: So in my example if I specify that $W=\{(x,y)|x=y\}$ assuming that $x,y$ are parameters in $\mathbb R$ could that be a valid example?

Comment: Yes that is a valid example (also known as $W=\{\,(x,x)\mid x\in\Bbb R\,\}$).

Comment: That's funny :)